# Payara Server not starting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, payara

I am currently trying to configure a Payara Server in Eclipse. When I try to launch the server it fails giving me this error Message

> Unable to start server due following issues: Launch process failed
>   with exit code 1

The Payara 5 [domain1] console only says

> Error: main class [9|]
>   --add-opens=java.rmi.sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED could not be opened or loaded

(for some reason this was German and I had to translate it for this post)

The server.log file under `D:\Server\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs` is completely empty.

I am using Eclipse 12-2019 and JDK 1.8 (12 and 13 would not work when creating the Server).

Help would be much appreciated.

Edit: In my Error Logs View in Eclipse I found the following:

```
org.eclipse.glassfish.tools.exceptions.GlassfishLaunchException: Launch process failed with exit code 1
    at 

    org.eclipse.glassfish.tools.GlassFishServerBehaviour$StartJob.call(GlassFishServerBehaviour.java:951)
        at org.eclipse.glassfish.tools.GlassFishServerBehaviour$StartJob.call(GlassFishServerBehaviour.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which version of Payara are you using? Did you try with the current version of the Eclipse Glassfish Tools 1.0.1?

Comment: I am using Payara Server 5.194. I installed GlassFish Tools 1.0.1 from [here](https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/repository/), in addition to Payara Server tool as mentioned in the answer. Still having the same issue as described in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar the problem, I updated the eclipse marketplace, and install payara server tools lastest version, and add server in the Runtime Environments in Servers in eclipse settings, and works for me...

Comment: My Payara Server was already added in the Server Runtime Environments. I installed the Payara Server Tools as you said, but I am still getting the same error message, terminal output and an empty log file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is working now. Thanks to the other people in this thread I tried the following things.

The solution may be all of the following, or a combination:

- Install Payara Server tools from marketplace.
- Install Glassfish Server tools. (Did not work for me from marketplace. I had to "Install new Software" under Help and get it from [this repository](https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.1/repository/) which is the current version as of this writing)
- Under "Server and Runtime" in Eclipse Preferences I set Payara.
- I deleted my Payara Server 5 from Server Runtime Environments in Preferences and re-added it.

I hope this is helpful for anyone having the same Issue.